# Why did the author use "do not" in which should have been "will not"?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

> **I do not** invoke religion to defend beard, but, attempt to remove many misconceptions that the author seems to be having regarding beard.

Should it be "do not" or "will not"? It implies the forthcoming writing which she was to write (future). What is the meaning of "do not" here?

I think "do not" is for state verbs like "think", "dismiss": mental exertion. "Do not" cannot be used for future stuff. Like "I do not go there" etc... "I do not think so" seems correct.

Comment: The quote is not grammatical. It should be either "beards" or "the beard".  Also can you add more detail why you think "do not" is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In English, a lot depends on the writer's intended *point of view* (POV).  You can see this most often with the use of the verbs "go" and "come":

> Will you **go** to the party with me?  (POV is *here*, where we are, traveling *there* to the party)
>
> Will you **come** to the party with me? (POV is *there* at the party, even if we are not actually in that location yet)

In your question the author's POV is *at the time of writing*.  It doesn't matter whether the argument was written in the past, or will be written in the future, the perspective is as if it is happening *now*.

One of the more famous examples of this is [Mark Antony's speech](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/56968/speech-friends-romans-countrymen-lend-me-your-ears) from the play "Julius Caesar", by William Shakespeare:

> Friends, Romans, countrymen, lend me your ears;
>   I **come** to bury Caesar, not to praise him.

Mark Antony is saying that he is here, *now*, to say something to his fellow Romans.  He hasn't said it yet, but his POV is as of the time he will be saying it.

In the same way, in your quoted text the author is saying, "The argument I present *at this moment* (is for a particular purpose)".  In many cases this use is more common than the future tense, especially if the time frame is not important.  For example:

> I **don't** say I dislike him because I disagree with him; I **say** it because he is a dislikable person.

In this sentence, it doesn't matter *when* said "I dislike him".  The point is that my dislike is kind of *timeless* and *ongoing*.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the foreword of a book. It likely says do not as the point she is making has already been written. However, using "will not" would not be incorrect either. In this context the two are more or less interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

**I do not** + {bare infinitive} is often used like "I am not" + {present participle}.

When the verb is a verb of saying (say, invoke, mention, etc) the locution leads to the reason for saying what is being said *now, at this very moment*, after dispelling some false notions the listener may have.  The emphasis is on what is happening in the present instant just as it can be with the present continuous.

> You should spend more time with your children. I **do not say this** to make you feel bad but to give you some good advice.
>
> You should spend more time with your children. I **am not saying this** to make you feel bad but to give you some good advice.

A slightly less informal version of negation:

> You should spend more time with your family. I **say this not** to make you feel bad but to give you some good advice.
>
> You should spend more time with your family. I **am saying this not** to make you feel bad but to give you some good advice.